# this returns undefined: (node:3196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'myArray' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

Here's my code:

https://github.com/DavidNyan10/NewProject

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser')

const myString = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('John');
});

class myClass{
    constructor(filename){
        this.myArray = [];
        this.myArray.push(new Promise((res) => {
            fs.createReadStream('filename')
                  .pipe(csv(['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Address', 'Town', 'Country', 'Postcode']))
                  .on('data', (data) => {
                    return(data);
                  })
          }))
    }
    async myFunction() {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myString.includes(this.myArray[i]['phrase'])){
                if (this.cooled_down(i)){
                    this.approve(i, myString);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    cooled_down(i){
        dictionary = this.myArray[i]
        if (!dictionary.keys().includes('approved')){
            // Means we have never approved on this person!
            return True;
        } else{
            now = datetime.now();
            duration = now - datetime.fromtimestamp(dictionary['approved']);
            duration_seconds = duration.total_seconds();
            hours = divmod(duration_seconds, 3600)[0];
            if (hours >= 24){
                return True;
            } else{
                console.log("Couldn't approve " + dictionary['FirstName'] + "Cool Down time: " + 24 - hours);
            }
        }
        return False;
    }

    approve(i, myString){
        dictionary = this.myArray[i];
        try{
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(myString);
                console.log(dictionary['FirstName'])
                console.log(dictionary['Postcode'])
            }, 60 * 60 * 3);
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }

        now = datetime.now();
        this.myArray[i]['approved'] = now.timestamp();
    }
}

myObj = new myClass("myCSV.csv");
myString.then(myObj.myFunction);
```

It keeps saying

```
(node:3196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'myArray' of undefined
    at myFunction (D:\projects\newproject\index.js:20:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3196) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

But as you can clearly see, `this.myArray` is clearly defined well on line 10.

What is going on?

I'm pretty new to javascript classes and objects, so I'm sorry if I looks dumb.

Also, any ideas how i can make line 11-17 better? I'm just putting the csv into an array but I don't know if that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `myString.then(myObj.myFunction)`. This is changing `this` keyword from `myObj` to something else. If you want to keep the context of the `this` keyword you need to bind `this` manually or call the function instead of passing it into `then` callback. Example:

```js
// Binding `this` to object:
myString.then(myObj.myFunction.bind(myObj));

// or
// Calling the function inside anonymous function instead 
// of passing it to `then` callback:
myString.then(() => myObj.myFunction());
```

Comment: Oh man, thank you very much! Now, the code runs without any errors but the problem is that it isn't returning who John is..

Comment: @DavidNyan10 your `myString` contains `Promise`. Not `string`. You need to pass string to `myFnuction` as argument.